# Log all console output in real time

Tags: scripting, logs

I would like to log everything printed to my console in real time. What I mean by this is that I need to be able to view the log file while the logger is running.

To my understanding, `script output.txt` cannot do this, because I cannot `more` the file until I `exit`. So what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The script manpage lists this option:

> `--flush`:
>   Flush output after each write.  This  is  nice  for 
>   telecooperation: one  person  does `mkfifo foo; script -f foo`, 
>   and another can supervise real-time what is being done using `cat foo`.

It sounds sufficient for what you want to achieve.